# Did each Horcrux represent a part of Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

Voldemort, knowingly, created 6 Horcruxes.

Of these, each seemed to resemble some part of the body.

1. The Diary seems to have a brain of its own. It is the only non-living Horcrux that seems to be capable of independent thought and action, and even memories (It remembers whatever Ginny writes)
2. The Locket resembles a heart, and Ron even feels so the first time he touches the locket.

   > He handed the locket back to Ron and Hermione, each of whom did their best, but were no more successful at opening it than he had been.
   >
   > “Can you feel it, though?” Ron asked in a hushed voice, as he held it tight in his clenched fist.
   >
   > “What d’you mean?”Ron passed the Horcrux to Harry. After a moment or two, Harry thought he knew what Ron meant. Was it his own blood pulsing through his veins that he could feel, or was it something beating inside the locket, like a tiny metal heart?
3. The diadem bled as it was destroyed in the Fiendfyre.

   > A bloodlike substance, dark and tarry, seemed to be leaking from the diadem. Suddenly Harry felt the thing vibrate violently, then break apart in his hands.

The Ring, and Nagini, don't add any sense to this theory. The cup was destroyed off-pages by Hermione, and nobody talks about it much, except to say Harry would look stupid with it hanging off his neck.

Are there any indications of the other Horcruxes exhibiting such behaviour, like they represent a particular body part? Or is it just coincidence?

Comment: You have already answered your question in the description itself, the ring, cup and Nagini in canon did not exhibit anything like you have already mentioned. It is also unknown whether it is the owners choice of which part to have in which horcrux, which leaves Harry as an exception because he is an unintended Horcrux. So, it maybe coincidence

Comment: And yet, when the locket was opened up, Tom Riddle's eyes were behind the glass windows, which is more where I thought you'd be going with this when I saw your question title. Personally, I'm not convinced there's much to it. Ginny Weasley got too close to Riddle's diary and that gave life and form to the Horcrux piece. It gave life to a whole Riddle. There was never any physical manifestation of a brain in the diary. It was just a normal diary on the outside, as far as anyone could see and when stabbed it bled ink, but there was nothing brain-y about it

Comment: Also, certainly, you could interact with the diary, but that's because the horcrux was a diary, which you could write in, so you could interact with the soul piece by those means. But you can't write in a locket. However, the locket, too, was able to interact with Harry & Ron and show those visions of Harry and Hermione entwined and torment Ron once it was opened, so there was nothing so special about the diary interacting, I don't think, that would make me think it was brain-like

Comment: I know which part of my body Nagini would represent. Heh heh... /s

Answer (score 4):

I think it is coincidence. Based on following:

> “You are thinking of Portkeys, Harry, which must be ordinary objects, easy to overlook. But would Lord Voldemort use tin cans or old potion bottles to guard his own precious soul? You are forgetting what I have showed you. Lord Voldemort liked to collect trophies, and he preferred objects with a powerful magical history. His pride, his belief in his own superiority, his determination to carve for himself a startling place in magical history; these things, suggest to me that Voldemort would have chosen his Horcruxes with some care, favoring objects worthy of the honor.”
>
> “The diary wasn’t that special.”
>
> “The diary, as you have said yourself, was proof that he was the Heir of Slytherin. I am sure that Voldemort considered it of stupendous importance.”
>
> <sub><sup>***Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23, Horcruxes***</sup></sub>

Secondly Horcruxes are created by splitting the soul and not body.

> “Well, you split your soul, you see,” said Slughorn, “and hide part of it in an object outside the body. Then, even if one’s body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die, for part of the soul remains earthbound and undamaged. But of course, existence in such a form...”
>
> <sub><sup>***Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23, Horcruxes***</sup></sub>

Comment: `the Hire of Slytherin`... shouldn't that be `the Heir of Slytherin`?

Answer (score 0):

## Likely no - they were each an enchanted body for their soul piece.

The Dark Lord’s Horcruxes don’t seem in any way to represent different parts of his body. However, the reason they act like bodies in some ways, like ‘bleeding’ when stabbed and having a ‘heartbeat’ may be because they act as the enchanted body for the soul piece encased within them.

> “But my point is that whatever happens to your body, your soul will survive, untouched,’ said Hermione. ‘But it’s the other way round with a Horcrux. The fragment of soul inside it depends on its container, its enchanted body, for survival. It can’t exist without it.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 6 (The Ghoul in Pyjamas)*</sup></sub>

This seems to be the most likely reason why the Horcruxes sometimes display behavior similar to  what a body might do, rather than them each representing separate parts of the Dark Lord’s body.